# AWS Control Tower existing audit and log account

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an AWS organization with all different core accounts - audit, log, etc.

Now I want to setup Control Tower to manage my accounts. At Control Tower setup, AWS want to provision an account for logs and audit, how can I tell Control Tower to use the existing audit and log account please ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in the new UI [you can specify if you want to use existing accounts](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/use-existing-logging-and-security-account-with-aws-control-tower/):

> In order for AWS Control Tower to create these accounts, customers must enter unique email addresses for each account. Once the setup is complete, customers can create new AWS Accounts or bring existing accounts under AWS Control Tower Management. See About AWS accounts in AWS Control Tower to learn more.